# Google SDK 1.9.1 on iOS & Swift xctest trouble

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, xctest

thanks in advance for the help that you can provide me. Im new in iOS and am developing an app that uses google maps. I added necessary frameworks and resources how google says in his documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start). The problem is when I'm trying to compile the app using XCTest, it returns this error : [image]

I made a project like tutorial in Swift using this SDK without unit test and it works fine.

Any help that you can provide me, i'll be thankful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem that you havent added all required frameworks to your project, or you did not copy the framework or bundle correctly.

You can try to go over [this Google Maps in Swift tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift), and download its project code, see if it runs with your XCode.

Comment: I created an other project without XCTest and it works fine. The problem comes when i added this line: GMSServices.provideAPIKey() on AppDelegate.

Comment: Have you added a `Bridge-Header` file?

Comment: Yes. The problem comes when i tried to compile TestTarget and it not support arm64 architect.

-> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:

Comment: I solved it. Just added GoogleMaps.Framework and others frameworks to TestTarget -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Library.